# How can I make a shared cache for multiple resources instead of IResourceScopeCache

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext

I would like to cache the same info or multiple files. for example I have a package and I want to import it in multiple files, I don't want to calculate the importing scope for the same import in different files. I want to calculate it once and cache it and then use it for multiple files.

Any idea or advice on how to make it like the current IResourceScopeCache?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the cache associated with the first resource in the resourceset.